# Install Cypress for API Automation Testing

Tags: cypress, web-api-testing

I am new to Cypress and trying to use it for API testing. Currently, I am using Cypress for UI automation and installed it in the **client** directory.

Now I have a confusion, If I am going to use Cypress for API testing do I need to install it again in the **server** directory? Or is the **client** directory also fine for API testing?

[image]

Comment: `client` & `server` directories of what technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client directory is absolutely fine and it should be done there.

[Here](https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-api-testing) is a nice article and plugin related to API testing.